Mudform is not providing live validation feedback while user is typing
Usually, when setting up a "MudForm" with live validation, the guiding validation messages from the validator class will automatically pop up below the form field when something is worng. This is not happening in my case for whatever reason.
When there is a validation error, and the user tries to submit, the form is also valid, which seems weird.
Here is the validator class:
public class CompanyUserValidator : AbstractValidator<CompanyUser>
{
    public CompanyUserValidator()
    {
        RuleFor(x => x.FirstName).NotEmpty().WithMessage("bla bla bla");
// and so on

    }

    public Func<object, string, Task<IEnumerable<string>>> ValidateValue => async (model, propertyName) =>
    {
        var result = await ValidateAsync(ValidationContext<CompanyUser>.CreateWithOptions((CompanyUser)model, x => x.IncludeProperties(propertyName)));
        if (result.IsValid)
            return Array.Empty<string>();
        return result.Errors.Select(e => e.ErrorMessage);
    };
}


Here is the form:
<MudForm Model="@companyUser" @ref="form" Validation="@(validator.ValidateValue)" ValidationDelay="0">
    <MudGrid Style="padding: 12px;">
        <MudItem xs="12" sm="6"><MudTextField T="string" @bind-Value="companyUser.FirstName" Label="Fornavn" Variant="Variant.Outlined" Immediate="true" For="@(() => companyUser.FirstName)" /></MudItem>
        <MudItem xs="12" sm="6"><MudTextField InputType="@InputType.Text" @bind-Value="companyUser.LastName" Label="Etternavn" Variant="Variant.Outlined" Immediate="true" For="(() => companyUser.LastName)" /></MudItem>
        <MudItem xs="12" sm="6"><MudTextField InputType="@InputType.Text" @bind-Value="companyUser.Name" Label="Firma navn" Variant="Variant.Outlined" Immediate="true" For="(() => companyUser.Name)" /></MudItem>
        <MudItem xs="12" sm="6"><MudTextField InputType="@InputType.Number" @bind-Value="companyUser.CompanyNumber" Label="Organisasjonsnummer" Variant="Variant.Outlined" Immediate="true" For="(() => companyUser.CompanyNumber)" /></MudItem>
        <MudItem xs="12" sm="12" md="4"><MudTextField InputType="@InputType.Text" @bind-Value="companyUser.Address.StreetAddress" Label="Adresse" Variant="Variant.Outlined" Immediate="true" For="(() => companyUser.Address.StreetAddress)" /></MudItem>
        <MudItem xs="12" sm="6" md="4"><MudTextField InputType="@InputType.Text" @bind-Value="companyUser.Address.PostalCode" Label="Postkode" Variant="Variant.Outlined" Immediate="true" For="(() => companyUser.Address.PostalCode)" /></MudItem>
        <MudItem xs="12" sm="6" md="4"><MudTextField InputType="@InputType.Text" @bind-Value="companyUser.Address.City" Label="Poststed" Variant="Variant.Outlined" Immediate="true" For="(() => companyUser.Address.City)" /></MudItem>
        <MudItem xs="12" sm="6"><MudTextField InputType="@InputType.Text" @bind-Value="companyUser.Email" Label="E-post" Variant="Variant.Outlined" Immediate="true" For="(() => companyUser.Email)" /></MudItem>
        <MudItem xs="12" sm="6"><MudTextField InputType="@InputType.Text" @bind-Value="companyUser.PhoneNumber" Label="Mobilnummer" Variant="Variant.Outlined" Immediate="true" For="(() => companyUser.PhoneNumber)" /></MudItem>
        <MudItem xs="12" sm="12">
            <MudButton ButtonType="ButtonType.Button" OnClick="@((e) => ValidateForm())" Variant="Variant.Outlined" Color="Color.Primary">Registrer deg</MudButton>
        </MudItem>
    </MudGrid>
</MudForm>

I've tried follwoing mudblazor's documentation, but that does not help.

FIxed it, had a mudform inside an editform.

The mudform presented was a child of an EditForm, this was hard to see because this component was referenced. Fixed.

The live validation needs page to be "Interactive" rendermode. Following small sample works as your description.
    public class CompanyUser
    {
        public string FirstName { get; set; }
        public string LastName { get; set; }
    }

@page "/"
@using FluentValidation
@using FluentValidation.Results
@rendermode InteractiveServer


<MudForm Model="@companyUser" Validation="@(validator.ValidateValue)" ValidationDelay="0">
    <MudGrid Style="padding: 12px;">
        <MudItem xs="12" sm="6"><MudTextField T="string" @bind-Value="companyUser.FirstName" Label="Fornavn" Variant="Variant.Outlined" Immediate="true" For="@(() => companyUser.FirstName)" /></MudItem>
        <MudItem xs="12" sm="6"><MudTextField InputType="@InputType.Text" @bind-Value="companyUser.LastName" Label="Etternavn" Variant="Variant.Outlined" Immediate="true" For="(() => companyUser.LastName)" /></MudItem>

        <MudItem xs="12" sm="12">
            <MudButton ButtonType="ButtonType.Button" OnClick="@((e) => ValidateForm())" Variant="Variant.Outlined" Color="Color.Primary">Registrer deg</MudButton>
        </MudItem>
    </MudGrid>
</MudForm>

@if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(validationMessage))
{
    <p>@validationMessage</p>
}

@code{
    private string validationMessage;

    private CompanyUser companyUser = new();

    CompanyUserValidator validator = new CompanyUserValidator();

    private async Task ValidateForm(){
        ValidationResult result = await validator.ValidateAsync(companyUser);

        if (result.IsValid)
        {
            validationMessage = "Form is valid!";
        }
        else
        {
            validationMessage = "Form is invalid!";
            foreach (var error in result.Errors)
            {
                validationMessage += $"\n{error.ErrorMessage}";
            }
        }
    }
}

Test result


Hey, thanks for answering. I should also mention I am using blazor wasm. I tried referencing the component with the RenderMode set to interactive wasm as I am not able to set the rendermode directly in the component, but that did not work. <SignUpCompanyUser @rendermode="RenderMode.InteractiveAuto" />

@OlaHagen I also tested with a "Web App auto/perpage" template and works.  I suggest you test with a brandnew project.
